# PHP - Combining multidimensional arrays with like keys

Tags: php, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have an array that I want to clean up.

```
0 => 
array
  'product_id' => string '24' (length=2)
  'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
1 => 
array
  'product_id' => string '40' (length=2)
  'qty' => string '4' (length=1)
2 => 
array
  'product_id' => string '40' (length=2)
  'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
3 => 
array
  'product_id' => string '24' (length=2)
  'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
4 =>
array
  'product_id' => string '24' (length=2)
  'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
```

I want to combine arrays by qty where their product_id keys match and return the same structure. So the above output would return:

```
0 => 
array
  'product_id' => string '24' (length=2)
  'qty' => string '3' (length=1)
1 => 
array
  'product_id' => string '40' (length=2)
  'qty' => string '5' (length=1)
```

Is there any way to do this while only looping over the array once? What is the best way to handle this?

**Note**

I understand the design isn't ideal, but I'm not asking about the design. I'm only asking about an efficient way to get the desired output.

Comment: This array suffers from poor design. Assuming the `product_id` is already unique why are these stored in a nested array instead of using the keys of the first array as the `product_id`

Comment: I appreciate your input, but this isn't helpful. The array is being created somewhere else and this is just a snippet of 2 out of several keys.

Comment: Are you open to suggestions on the output? The output format is obfuscated and would be much easier to implement if the `product_id` became the primary key instead of an arbitrary number. Also is code you wrote generating the initial array, or is it an API into someone else's?

Comment: The array is being pulled from a database. The table it's being pulled from has several columns, including other ids, like user_id etc.

Comment: Could you query your database to aggregate these columns prior to having to do post-processing in PHP?

Comment: I can, and probably will end up doing that. However, since I stumbled upon the problem, I was wondering if there was a way to do what I displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `product_id` as the key in your result array as suggested in the comments, condensing the items this way is pretty simple.

```
foreach ($initial_array as $item) {
    $combined_array[$item['product_id']]['product_id'] = $item['product_id'];
    $combined_array[$item['product_id']]['qty'] += $item['qty'];
}
```

This approach will preserve the original format while collecting the quantity field. You will have `product_id`s as keys in the outer array rather than just 0,1,etc., and if this is a problem (I can't see why it would be), you can use `array_values` to get them back to a normal zero indexed array.

Comment: This works great thanks. Don't understand the down-vote on the question however.

Comment: You're welcome. According to the text on the down-vote arrow, I assume that since the question was not unclear and was useful, the down-vote was from someone who thought the question showed no research effort.

Comment: Yeah the semicolon after that led me to believe it was either unclear or not useful. I certainly did some research and came to the same answer you gave me. I just didn't know about array_values and was stuck thinking I needed it to be indexed that way for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the inside array has only 2 elements, you could use something like this:

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($cleanarray as $array){
        $newarray[$array[0]] += $array[1];
}
```

You'd have to change it to fit your needs, but the output I got from running this on your initial array was:

```
Array ( [24] => 3 [40] => 5 )
```

Comment: The quantity is not necessarily 1, see the second entry.

Comment: Yeah. I just noticed that and added to my answer.